# JSF 2.0 -- Share or Prime OmniFaces Combined Resource Cache Across Cluster

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources, cluster-computing, omnifaces

Is there a way in JSF to use a combined resource across a cluster? Basically I'm looking for a solution where the first server in the cluster to introduce the resource could synchronize that to the resource cache of the other servers.

Comment: What kind of resources do you mean?

Comment: @Adrian: the files in `/resources` folder which are handled by `ResourceHandler`.

Comment: Why would you need that cache synchronization as only static resources get cached?

Comment: In the case of Omnifaces, the CombinedResourceHandler introduces combined CSS/JS resources to the resource cache as pages are rendered that include h:outputScript or h:outputStylesheet resources. So if the request for the xhtml page comes into one server that server will process the combined resource and place it in the resource cache, but then if the http request for the resource itself comes into a different server it will not necessarily be availble, thus my question. I made it general though as I figured there would likely be other applications for this.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I didn't thought about this at all. Theoretically this could be solved by using a different unique ID approach which allows for two-way conversion between all the combined resources and its short unique identifier. Perhaps I'd need to use Base64 instead of MD5.

Comment: That would be a fantastic solution. Then the resources could still be resolved even if the page hadn't yet been accessed (like when we roll the cluster) ... I can open a feature request if you like?

Comment: For now i have a temp solution using nginx to check for the resources on each upstream server but it's not very lovely.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=53

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not possible because the unique ID of the combined resource was generated based on MD5 which is an irreversible one-way encryption. So if the resource is created on server X and requested on server Y, then server Y won't be able to resolve the resources from the cache based on the unique ID.

Since OmniFaces 1.2 this has been fixed by replacing the MD5 approach by a combination of ZLIB and Base64 which makes it short and reversible. Server Y will now be able to resolve the resources itself based on the ID and then store in the cache.

There's by the way an additional step to the Base64 encoding approach in form of replacing the `/`, `+` and `=` characters by `~`, `-` and `_` to make it [URL-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters) so that it can without any much possibly platform-sensitive URL-encoding hassle be passed through URLs.

Comment: Omnifaces is getting so awesome. You have really made my software stack infinitely better. I'm forever grateful.